# how to merge these complex array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have two arrays:

1st array:

```
$a=array
    (
     [0]=>array
               (
                [row]=>array
                  (
                    [0]=>array
                      (
                       [type]=>3
                       [addres]=>'abc'
                       [invi]=>5
                       )
                    )
                  )
        )
```

2nd Array:

```
$b=array(
[usn]=>43
[ssn]=>52
)
```

I want to merge both the arrays.so that the resultant array will look like:

```
$c=array
        (
         [0]=>array
                   (
                    [row]=>array
                      (
                        [0]=>array
                          (
                           [type]=>3
                           [addres]=>'abc'
                           [invi]=>5
                           [usn]=>43
                           [ssn]=>52
                           )
                        )
                      )
            )
```

I have tried `array_merge()`,but its not giving me the output I want.

**How to achieve the above $c array by merging $a and $b array?**

Comment: You don't provide us any information about how should it work in general. Basing on what you wrote, you should merge `$b` with `$a[0]['row'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = array_merge($a[0]['row'][0],$b);
$a[0]['row'][0] = $c;
$c = $a;

//resultant array is
print_r($c);
```